# how to substract or abstract cart qty in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, e-commerce, cart

I Am using this package
gloudemans/shoppingcart
now i have button Like This
[image]

i have created 2 routes cartqtyminus & cartqtyplus

How to update cart with these buttons
button has href tag

Comment: `preventDefault()` will prevent the href from refreshing the page. Make it ajax instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i just did like this for plus

```
 $rowId = $cart;
        $product = Cart::get($rowId);
        $productqty = $product->qty;
        $updateqty = $productqty+1;
        Cart::update($rowId, $updateqty);
        return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'update Success');
```

for minus

```
 $rowId = $cart;
        $product = Cart::get($rowId);
        $productqty = $product->qty;
        $updateqty = $productqty-1;
        Cart::update($rowId, $updateqty);
        return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'update Success');
```

Answer (score -1):

Do that really simply using `increment()` and `decrement()` methods.

`Cart::class` is your model so you can do:

`Cart::findOrFail(ID)->increment('points')` or `Cart::findOrFail(ID)->decrement('points')`

Read more in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#updates).

Now make your button which is sending PATCH form (with `type` field) to below route:

```
Route::patch('{cart}/vote', ['as' => 'cart.vote', 'uses' => 'YourController@vote]);
```

In your controller you can make method:

```
public function vote(Cart $cart)
{
    request()->get('type') === 'up' ? $cart->increment('points') : $cart->decrement('points');

    return redirect()->route('your.main.route');
}
```